# ¿Como guardar posición de nav scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como puedo guardar la posicion del nav en los li si refresco la pagina, por ejemplo si yo doy en el nav en nosotros y refresco la pagina, el div nosotros se queda en la pantalla pero el nav li sube en home.¿como lo soluciono?

```
<!-- nav_right -->
     <div class="nav_right">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home"><span class="active"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#nosotros"><span></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#trabajos"><span></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#trabajos2"><span></span></a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <!-- fin del nav_right -->
```

este es el js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  // elementos de la lista
  var menues = $("li a span");
  // manejador de click sobre todos los elementos
  menues.click(function() {
    // eliminamos active de todos los elementos
    menues.removeClass("active");
      // activamos el elemento clicado.
      $(this).addClass("active");
  });

});
```

Este es otro js en el html

```
<!-- smooth scroll -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event){
      //Aquí elimina el evento normal de la etiqueta <a>
      event.preventDefault();
      //Aquí cojemos el elmento
      var elem=$(this).attr("href");
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(elem).offset().top
      },800);
    });
  });
</script>
<!-- fin del smooth scroll -->
```